# Command line within python script giving syntax error

Tags: python, command, ipython, spyder

I am  trying to run a simple command line from python.
While the code works in Jupyter notebook it throws syntax error in Spyder.

Strangely if I run the same command line within test() below inside console it executes but script shows error.

Below is my code. TIA!

```
def test():
    !start excel

test()
```

Comment: `!start excel` is not valid python. Jupyter has a speclal escape code `!` to be able to run native commands. But that's not valid python

Answer (score 3):

`!start excel` works in Jupyter notebook because the Jupyter shell is able to understand the `!` prefix and run a native (Windows) command.

> `!`: to run a shell command. E.g., ! pip freeze | grep pandas to see what version of pandas is installed.

But `!start excel` isn't valid python syntax. You need the exact python equivalent (for Windows at least):

```
import os
os.startfile("excel")
```